# Markup extension does not work at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, design-time, markup-extensions

I have markup extensions to allow me use binding and cell template in `GridView` at the same time. It works fine at runtime, but it does not work at design time, wondering if there is anything I could do to fix that. I've tested returning simple string instead of `DataTemplate` just to make sure, that custom markup extensions work in general at design time - and it worked, so it should be somehow related to the fact, that `DataTemplate` is returned.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(DataTemplate))]
public class TemplateBuilderExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public TemplateBuilderExtension() { }
    public TemplateBuilderExtension(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    // Here be dirty hack.
    internal static string TagPath { get; private set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        TagPath = Path;
        var resourceExt = new StaticResourceExtension("GridViewTextCell");

        // This line causes the evaluation of the Tag as the resource is loaded.        
        var baseTemplate = (DataTemplate)resourceExt.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

        return baseTemplate;
    }
}

[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingExpression))]
public class TemplateBuilderTagExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public TemplateBuilderTagExtension()
    {           
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new Binding(TemplateBuilderExtension.TagPath);
    }
}

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Shared="false" x:Key="GridViewTextCell">
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{markupExtensions:TemplateBuilderTag}"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources> 
<Grid>      
    <ListView SelectedIndex="5">        
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" CellTemplate="{markupExtensions:TemplateBuilder Id}" Width="300"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>        
</Grid>
```

Update: I've simplified code to be as short as possible, in real situation there are multiple GridView's through application, each grid contains multiple columns and those columns should reuse same template and also I can't use DataGrid because of performance issues.

Comment: I don't get the idea of this yet. What do you mean by " use binding and cell template" ? Is it you want the datacontext of visual parents in your celltemplate ? Then you could go a much simpler way

Comment: Thing is, that if you wish to use cell template, you need to define it for each column, because you can't pass binding path to cell template. Code in question solves the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a candidate for a DataTemplate Selector ?

Comment: From GridViewRowPresenter code it looks like it would not help - it would simply use class for selecting cell template, but would do nothing with bindings.

Comment: Well in your case, it's the CellTemplateSelector, and it allows you to select the appropriate template for your column. No need to use template binding then.

Comment: Yes, but if you would have separate template for each column, you would not reuse template's code, that is the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You would normally solve that using your derived and base class architecture in c#, and specifiy that classname for the template. 2ndly) in pure Xaml, you can use style inheritance using BasedOn.

Comment: You could refer to styles / static resources in your datatemplates. These can be nested like your logic wants it, and at the same way eleminating any redundant code!

Comment: Could you provide example, because I'm not sure if I get the idea?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that it is your goal to get rid of redundant code in the templates ?

Comment: My goal is to use same template for all columns, just bind text block inside that template to different field according to a column,

Comment: ok - since i just saw your approach it's plausible you want to keep the ContentPresenter inside the template structure. It seems you gonna program by hand the autogenerating columns, that would be provided by the WPF Datagrid. If the Datagrid is unacceptable and your solution causes problems, there are lots of 3rd party Datagrids (Telerik, DevExpress) around. Just a hint & Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this just very recently as well.
Turns out, somehow I had disabled project code in the WPF designer.
**Enabling project code** made the markup extension work as desired.

[image]

taken from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer#to-disable-project-code-in-the-designer).

Comment: Never underestimate small buttons.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was pulling my hair out as to why none of my custom controls were rendering in the designer suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Your extensions do not make much sense. That all can be written like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="path">thatPath<sys:String/>

    <DataTemplate x:Shared="false" x:Key="GridViewTextCell">
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={StaticResource path}}"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources> 
<Grid>      
    <ListView SelectedIndex="5">        
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewTextCell}" Width="300"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>        
</Grid>
```

Binding itself is also an extension. You sort of trying to extend a extension...

How about you leave it be and use the normal approach instead? :)

Comment: Ok, what if cell template is complex enough, that you would not like to repeat it for each column in the GridView through all GridViews within an application? Let's say you need to have 10 columns in a grid and all should use same cell template, but different binding (bindings are simple, same view model, different properties)?

Comment: Sadly, it does not work this way, as long as you set `DisplayMemberBinding`, `CellTemplate` property value is ignored.

Comment: I do not think so :) It works for me. Can you please upload your project?

Comment: If you would take a look at [GridViewRowPresenter source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewRowPresenter@cs/1/GridViewRowPresenter@cs), CreateCell method, you would notice, that if DisplayMemberBiding is set, only TextBlock is created, so you should not see border from my example.

Comment: I checked out that link. You were right. I think I mixed GridView with DataGrid.. Your issue is really very stupid. Maybe this link will help you any futher. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752313(v=vs.110).aspx Its about using GridViewRowPresenter. btw, how about you try DataGrid?

Comment: DataGrid is too slow in my use case, I've tried it and it was noticeably slower.

Comment: DataGrid shouldnt run slow when you enable virtualization. How about you work with ListView but you override the ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride method. There you will be able to configure each container/row before they are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided to use following approach:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="TestColumn">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TestProperty}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewTextCell}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

So, wrapping template into `ContentPresenter` allows to use binding I wish and reuse template.

Following this, it is possible to go further, I have working concept, but decided not to use it (at least yet). Idea is to automatically generate columns, by getting public properties of ItemsSource, which might be further improved by creating attribute, which would define header description and width:

```
public class ExtendedListView : ListView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoColumnsProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register("AutoColumns", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, OnAutoColumnsPropertyChanged));

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        OnAutoColumnsPropertyChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(AutoColumnsProperty, false, true));
    }

    private static void OnAutoColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

        var dataGrid = (ExtendedListView)d;

        if (newValue)
        {
            dataGrid.AddAutoColumns();
        }
        else
        {
            dataGrid.DeleteAutoColumns();
        }           
    }

    Type GetBaseTypeOfEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            return null;                
        }

        var genericEnumerableInterface = enumerable
            .GetType()
            .GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

        if (genericEnumerableInterface == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var elementType = genericEnumerableInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (!elementType.IsGenericType)
        {
            return elementType;
        }

        return elementType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
            ? elementType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
            : elementType;
    }

    private readonly HashSet<GridViewColumn> autoGeneratedColumns = new HashSet<GridViewColumn>();

    private void AddAutoColumns()
    {
        var gridView = View as GridView;

        if (gridView == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a grid view");
        }

        var itemType = GetBaseTypeOfEnumerable(ItemsSource);

        if (itemType == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not resolve item type");
        }

        var properties = itemType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn
            {
                CellTemplate = CreateTemplate(property.Name),
                Header = property.Name,
                Width = 100
            };

            gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);

            autoGeneratedColumns.Add(gridViewColumn);
        }           
    }

    private DataTemplate CreateTemplate(string path)
    {
        string xamlTemplate = string.Format("<DataTemplate><ContentPresenter Content=\"{{Binding {0}}}\" ContentTemplate=\"{{StaticResource GridViewTextCell}}\" /></DataTemplate>", path);

        var context = new ParserContext
        {
            XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0])
        };

        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

        var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(xamlTemplate, context);

        return template;
    }

    private void DeleteAutoColumns()
    {
        var gridView = View as GridView;

        if (gridView == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a grid view");
        }

        for (int columnIndex = gridView.Columns.Count - 1; columnIndex >= 0; --columnIndex)
        {
            if (autoGeneratedColumns.Contains(gridView.Columns[columnIndex]))
            {
                gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
            }
        }       
    }

    public bool AutoColumns
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AutoColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutoColumnsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```